# Grub2 EFI falls to Grub Shell unless I hit F12 immediately after power on

Tags: multi-boot, opensuse, grub2, efi

I have Opensuse Tumbleweed together with Windows 10 on my Asus ROG laptop.
The issue is quite weird - every time I power on or reboot, Grub2 EFI falls to grub2 shell and randomly it doesn't see the second hard drive.
But if I press F12 immediately after power on or during reboot, normal Grub2 menu appears and I can boot to Opensuse or Windows without a problem. That's quite annoying. Can anyone help me with this issue?
I didn't do any modifications to config files, except for adding entries in `/etc/fstab` to mount Windows partitions, but I don't believe it's related.

`/boot/efi/EFI/opensuse/grub.cfg:`

```
search --fs-uuid --set=root 884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
set prefix=(${root})/grub2
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

`/boot/grub2/grub.cfg:`

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub2-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -f ${config_directory}/grubenv ]; then
  load_env -f ${config_directory}/grubenv
elif [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi

if [ "${env_block}" ] ; then
  load_env -f "${env_block}"
fi

if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   if [ "${env_block}" ] ; then
     save_env -f "${env_block}" next_entry
   fi
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt 
insmod btrfs
set root='hd1,gpt3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt3  6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1
fi
    font="/.snapshots/1/snapshot/usr/share/grub2/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=POSIX
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod part_gpt 
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,gpt4'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt4  884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
fi
insmod gfxmenu
loadfont ($root)/grub2/themes/openSUSE/DejaVuSans-Bold14.pf2
loadfont ($root)/grub2/themes/openSUSE/DejaVuSans10.pf2
loadfont ($root)/grub2/themes/openSUSE/DejaVuSans12.pf2
loadfont ($root)/grub2/themes/openSUSE/ascii.pf2
insmod png
set theme=($root)/grub2/themes/openSUSE/theme.txt
export theme
if [ x${boot_once} = xtrue ]; then
  set timeout=0
elif [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=10
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_tuned ###
set tuned_params=""
### END /etc/grub.d/00_tuned ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed'  --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt 
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt4  884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-1-default ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-4.4.0-1-default root=UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 rootflags=subvol=.snapshots/1/snapshot  quiet splash=silent
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initrd-4.4.0-1-default
}
submenu 'Advanced options for openSUSE Tumbleweed' --hotkey=1 $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1' {
    menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed, with Linux 4.4.0-1-default' --hotkey=2 --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1-default-advanced-6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt 
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt4  884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-1-default ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.4.0-1-default root=UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 rootflags=subvol=.snapshots/1/snapshot  quiet splash=silent
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd-4.4.0-1-default
    }
    menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed, with Linux 4.4.0-1-default (recovery mode)' --hotkey=3 --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1-default-recovery-6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt 
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt4  884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-1-default ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.4.0-1-default root=UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 rootflags=subvol=.snapshots/1/snapshot  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd-4.4.0-1-default
    }
    menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed, with Linux 4.3.3-5-default'  --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.3.3-5-default-advanced-6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt 
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt4  884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.3.3-5-default ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.3.3-5-default root=UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 rootflags=subvol=.snapshots/1/snapshot  quiet splash=silent
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd-4.3.3-5-default
    }
    menuentry 'openSUSE Tumbleweed, with Linux 4.3.3-5-default (recovery mode)' --hotkey=1 --class opensuse --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.3.3-5-default-recovery-6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt 
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt4  884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.3.3-5-default ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.3.3-5-default root=UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 rootflags=subvol=.snapshots/1/snapshot  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd-4.3.3-5-default
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-AE4A-03B2' {
    insmod part_gpt 
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  AE4A-03B2
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AE4A-03B2
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/80_suse_btrfs_snapshot ###
### END /etc/grub.d/80_suse_btrfs_snapshot ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/90_persistent ###
### END /etc/grub.d/90_persistent ###
```

`/etc/fstab:`

```
UUID=2743aca8-ab1f-44d8-813d-bbb615ba4188 swap swap defaults 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 / btrfs defaults 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /home btrfs subvol=home 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /opt btrfs subvol=opt 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /srv btrfs subvol=srv 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /tmp btrfs subvol=tmp 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /usr/local btrfs subvol=usr/local 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/crash btrfs subvol=var/crash 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/lib/libvirt/images btrfs subvol=var/lib/libvirt/images 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/lib/mailman btrfs subvol=var/lib/mailman 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/lib/mariadb btrfs subvol=var/lib/mariadb 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/lib/mysql btrfs subvol=var/lib/mysql 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/lib/named btrfs subvol=var/lib/named 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/lib/pgsql btrfs subvol=var/lib/pgsql 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/log btrfs subvol=var/log 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/opt btrfs subvol=var/opt 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/spool btrfs subvol=var/spool 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /var/tmp btrfs subvol=var/tmp 0 0
UUID=6159e15d-f224-499d-88e0-437b5538f0f1 /.snapshots btrfs subvol=.snapshots 0 0
UUID=AE4A-03B2       /boot/efi            vfat       umask=0002,utf8=true  0 0
UUID=884f4184-2900-4123-a4be-60df5a0f0ad0    /boot/    ext2    rw,relatime,stripe=4    0 0
UUID=5644A7CA44A7AAE7 /windows             ntfs-3g    ro,users,gid=users,fmask=133,dmask=022,locale=pl_PL.UTF-8 0 0
UUID=EAAE2A7FAE2A4503 /windows/data-and-programs ntfs-3g    users,gid=users,fmask=133,dmask=022,locale=pl_PL.UTF-8 0 0
```

**EDIT:**
Output of `efibootmgr -v`:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0004
Boot0000* opensuse-secureboot   HD(1,GPT,5a12695d-97ad-485a-b393-c00a89d1b0d8,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\opensuse\shim.efi)
Boot0001* opensuse  HD(1,GPT,5a12695d-97ad-485a-b393-c00a89d1b0d8,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\opensuse\grubx64.efi)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,5a12695d-97ad-485a-b393-c00a89d1b0d8,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...d................
Boot0004* UEFI OS   HD(1,GPT,5a12695d-97ad-485a-b393-c00a89d1b0d8,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
```

Comment: So your windows and linux are on same drive, yes? That drive has a GPT, yes? You installed grub to the efi partition, yes?

Comment: @jiggunjer /boot/efi is on /dev/sda1 (fat32), Windows recovery partition is /dev/sda2, Windows C drive is /dev/sda3, Windows D drive is /dev/sdb1, Linux swap is /dev/sdb2, Linux / is on /dev/sdb3 (btrfs) , /boot/ is on /dev/sdb4 (ext2). Originally the whole /dev/sdb was only for Windows D drive. I have shrinked D drive and used the free space to install Opensuse with default options and grub2-efi has landed on /dev/sdb1 as expected. Yes, both hard disks have GPT.

Comment: @jiggunjer sorry, I've just noticed that I had a mistake in description. It doesn't fall to UEFI shell but to grub2 shell. Question edited already..

Comment: I don't understand why grub was installed to the windows data partition (sdb1). Your system tries to boot from sda1.

Comment: @jiggunjer grub is not on sda1. Where did I write something like this? grub.efi binary is in /boot/efi/EFI/opensuse/ (/boot/efi is sda1) and other grub files are in /boot/grub2 (/boot is sdb4)

Comment: grub.efi in /boot/efi = starting point. So that is on sda1, good. You said "grub2-efi has landed on /dev/sdb1", which is weird because sdb1 is not a boot partition.

Comment: You're right. I've written this - sorry. It's a typo. It is on sda1

Comment: I wish I knew what that f12 was doing. Did you check the UEFI firmware settings for any default boot behavior. maybe it is trying to load sdb4 directly, because of some flag? did you happen to remove a OEM recovery partition recently?

Comment: Legacy boot is disabled in UEFI settings, so it shouldn't try to respect the boot flag nor try to boot from anything else than FAT/FAT32 partition. In fact it loads grub2.efi cause it shows grub shell. F12 is indeed a mystery - if I press it, I get grub2 menu like it should always be and I can boot Opensuse or Windows without a hassle.

Comment: The annoing part is that I have only ~0.5 second between pressing power button and F12. Otherwise it's too late.

Comment: There's a possibility that the system is running an old GRUB from a previous installation (or from a failed recovery attempt), and that this is the problem. If so, it should show up in `efibootmgr -v` output. You can edit your original question to include that output if you need help interpreting it.

Comment: @RodSmith thanks for the hint. Output added to the question.

Comment: No, that looks OK. Another thought: Have you disabled the Windows 10 "Fast Startup" feature, as described [here?](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) You may also need to disable the "hibernation" feature, as described [here.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) If these features are enabled, they can leave shared partitions (including the ESP, where boot loaders reside) in an unstable state after Windows shuts down (because Windows never really completely shuts down).

Comment: I have both fast startup and hibernate disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By grub shell I assume you mean grub rescue shell instead of normal shell.

The reason is probably due to the fact that the "second drive" is not ready when the grub EFI binary on the ESP (which is on the "first drive") is executed by the UEFI, so the binary failed to locate the grub modules and grub.cfg (which is on the /boot directory of sdb3, if you don't have a partition for /boot).

To solve this you can try to disable any "fast boot" option in the UEFI setting (not Windows). <strike>If it still doesn't work, you may have to reinstall grub in a way that the modules and grub.cfg are put on the ESP as well (--boot-directory /boot/efi, suppose --efi-directory is /boot/efi as well).</strike> Or actually, you may want to try use the ESP for /boot, and hope that when the kernel try to mount the root filesystem (sdb3), the second drive is made ready by the UEFI.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using EFI partition as /boot mountpoint and installing grub with this layout solved the problem.